# How to show the content of request object (Pyramid1.4 production environment)

Tags: python, request, pyramid

I have the following error

```
line 668, in __getitem__
    return self._session()[key]
KeyError: 'last_update'
```

While on developement environment everything is OK. I use Pyramid 1.4 with waitress server under ngnix. Is anybody know how to use debug_tool API with pshell to display the content of request.session ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

After search I've decided to proceed as follow

- make a script to enable (and disable) the debug_tool panel (with 'debugtoolbar.hosts': '127.0.0.1')
- connect to the panel with SSH tunnel

Before doing it, is there a security issue to doing it or another way to access to the debug panel securely ?

Thanks,